# Use packrat with this project keeps asking to install additional tools

Tags: r, rstudio, packrat

When I

1. Go to the 'Packages' panel in RStudio.
2. Click 'Packrat'.
3. Check the 'Use packrat with this project' option.

I keep getting the popup window 'Install Build Tools' asking

> Managing packages with Packrat requires installation of additional build tools. Do you want to install the additional tools now?

I am using:

- R version 3.4.2
- packrat version 0.4.8-55
- RStudio version 1.1.383
- windows 10

When I initialize packrat manually in the project repository

`packrat::init()`

and install a new package I do not get the automated prompts (as described in the 'Making changes' section of http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/rstudio.html) either.

Does anyone know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and have not found a solution. However, you could try a couple of things (both of which I have tried to no avail...but perhaps they will work for you).

1. Try starting RStudio with admin rights (i.e. right click > Run as administrator) and seeing if it install properly then.
2. Failing that try downloading and installing Rtools manually ([cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)).
3. Also maybe check your environment variable path points to your install location of Rtools.